# Pivot Table in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm very new to python (using pandas). Kindly help.

There are two columns in my dataframe - weight conversion (float) and sales_units (int). **I simply want to group by (sum) the sales_units by weight_conversion.**

Sample Data

```
weight_conversion   sales_units
0.1                   1
0.1                   2
50                    100
50                    200
96.1                  20
314.4                  2
500                   100
500                   200
```

I have tried two ways:

1. GROUP BY IN PANDAS :

> `df.groupby(['weight_conversion'])['Sales_Unit'].sum()`

2. PIVOT TABLE IN PANDAS:

   > df.pivot_table(index = 'weight_conversion', values='Sales_Unit',
   > aggfunc ='sum')

Required Output: **I need a simple pivot table where I have rows as weight_conversion along with sum of sales units.**

**The output I'm getting in Python Pandas is as follows (so weird):**
weight_conversion

```
0       3300000000000000000000000000034000000000000000...
0.1     0000100001000000000000001000000020050000000000...
0.2     0000000000000000000000000000001000000001100000...
0.3                           000000000000000000000300000
0.4     0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000001...
                            ...                        
90                                        000000000102009
92      0000200011000000000000010001000000000000000020...
92.1                            0000001000000000000000003
96      2000000000000000000000000000000000001100000000...
96.1    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
```

Name: Sales_Unit, Length: 96, dtype: object

**sample output**

```
weight_conversion   sales_units
0.1                   3
50                    300
96.1                  20
314.4                  2
500                   300
```

Please help.**

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data as well as expected results?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn: Just edited and provided sample. Appreciate your comment. It would mean so much if you could help. :)

Comment: What's the problem with your tried two ways?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh: I think the problem was with my import data code df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', dtype=object). Once I removed dtype = object, the code worked. But I don't understand the logic. Can you explain why it worked after I removed the dtype = object?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need PIVOT table for the sample output you have given. Below worked as for the required output you mentioned

```html
df = pd.DataFrame({"weight_conversion":[0.1,0.1,50,50,96.1,314.4,500,500],
              "sales_units":[1,2,100,200,20,2,100,200]})
              
df.groupby('weight_conversion').agg({'sales_units':'sum'}).reset_index()

Output:
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Abhishek, actually I figured out my error. Since my file had all mixed type data I imported using df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', dtype = object). Once I removed dtype=object, my code was successful. My code is same as yours. Thank you for your time. :)